# gdborig.exe потребляет больше 1,2 Гб и роняет приложение

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, gdb

При отладке в Qt Creator 4.1.0 приложение падает, и появляется окно с сообщением

> Прекращена работа программы `gdborig.exe`.

Мною замечено, что такое происходит в момент когда `gdborig.exe` начинает потреблять памяти более 1,2 Гб. Нормально ли такое потребление памяти отладчиком, если да, то как мне это побороть и продолжить нормальную отладку приложения?

Как только вызывается функция `insertImpMetValue( pPulseMeter )` сразу происходит падение с сообщением

> Прекращена работа программы `gdborig.exe`.

Работал над функциями `insertVbatValue  ( pPulseMeter );` и `insertLiqMetValue( pPulseMeter );`, до которых отладчик даже не успевает дойти.

```
void CDatabaseDriverPSQL::insertPulseMeterPollResult( QList<CPulseMeter *> aPollResult )
{
    if( !aPollResult.isEmpty() )
    {
        foreach ( CPulseMeter *pPulseMeter, aPollResult )
        {
            insertImpMetValue( pPulseMeter );// падает здесь
            insertVbatValue  ( pPulseMeter );
            insertLiqMetValue( pPulseMeter );
        } // foreach
    }
    else AMR_ASSERT_FALSE();
}

void CDatabaseDriverPSQL::insertImpMetValue( const CPulseMeter *pPulseMeter )
{
    QList<qint32> aList = pPulseMeter->getPusleseCh();

    const int nData = 3 + aList.size() + aList.size();
    QVariantList aData[ nData ];

    aData[ 0 ] << pPulseMeter->getSerialNumber();
    aData[ 1 ] << pPulseMeter->getDateTimeDevice();
    aData[ 2 ] << pPulseMeter->getDataTransmissionTime();

    for( int i = 0 + 3; i < 3 + aList.size(); i++ )
    {
        aData[ i ] << aList[ i - 3 ];
    }

    QStringList aLiqSerNumbers = getLiqMetersSN( pPulseMeter->getSerialNumber() );
    for( int i = 3 + aList.size(); i < 3 + aList.size() + aList.size(); i++ )
    {
        aData[ i ] << aLiqSerNumbers[ i - 3 - aList.size() ];
    }

    QString sPulseCHs;
    for( int i = 1; i <= aList.size(); i++ )
    {
         QString sNumbers = QString( "PULSE_CH%1," ).arg( i );

         if( aList.size() == i )
         {
             sNumbers.remove( "," ); // обрезаем последнюю запятую
         }

         sPulseCHs.append( sNumbers );
    }

    QString sLiqMetSNs;
    for( int i = 1; i <= aList.size(); i++ )
    {
         QString sNumbers = QString( "LIQ_METER_SN_CH%1," ).arg( i );

         if( aList.size() == i )
         {
             sNumbers.remove( "," ); // обрезаем последнюю запятую
         }

         sLiqMetSNs.append( sNumbers );
    }

    QString sQuestionMarks;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3 + aList.size() + aList.size(); i++)
    {
        sQuestionMarks.append("?, ")  ;
        if( 3 + aList.size() + aList.size() == i )
        {
            sQuestionMarks.chop( 2 ); // обрезаем последнюю запятую
        }
    }

    QSqlQuery oSqlQuery;

    QString sQuery = QString( "INSERT INTO %1 ( IMP_METER_SN, IMP_DATE, MEASUREMENTS_TIME, %2, %3 ) VALUES( %4 )" )
                            .arg( AMR_TABLE_NAME_IMP_METER_VALUES ).arg( sPulseCHs ).arg( sLiqMetSNs ).arg( sQuestionMarks );

    oSqlQuery.prepare( sQuery );
    for( int i = 0; i < nData; i++ )
    {
        oSqlQuery.addBindValue( aData[ i ] );
    }

    if( oSqlQuery.execBatch() )
    {
    }
    else AMR_ASSERT_FALSE();
}
```

[image: снимок экрана с сообщениями об ошибке]

Comment: prig, orig... логично предположить, что кол-во потребляемой памяти зависит от того, что подаётся на вход. Кода Вы не привели, так что говорить о чём-то конкретном сложно.

Comment: Код не могу привести, т.к. 40k сторочек кода

Comment: значит надо сокращать код, пока ошибка не перестанет проявляться. После чего создать [mcve] и привести его здесь.

Comment: Вообще говоря, можно считать как факт, что для отладки нужно много ОЗУ. Не знаю, как другие отладчики, но gdb покушать любит.

Comment: Как я могу сокращатькод если он со временем будет только расти (добавляться новая функциональность, поддержка новых устройств и т .д.)? Т.е. вы хотите сказать, что я не смогу написать приложение свыше 40000 строк кода? Есть какое то ограничение на приложение Qt? Если есть я за этим сюда и пришёл, чтобы мне объяснили.

Comment: На моей рабочей машине 8 Гб ОЗУ и ни разу я и половины не занимал, даже во время отладки.

Comment: @ЕвгенийДружинин вы не так поняли. Я говорю о сокращении кода исключительно для поиска ошибки. А когда причина падения будет найдена и устранена, программу можно развивать дальше.

Comment: попробуйте использовать откладку Visual Studio. Для трансляции приложения в VS, войдите через консоль в папку приложения и введите `qmake -tp vc`

Comment: @alexolut Я можно сказать так и делал. В SVN встал на более старую версию, которая стопроцентно отлаживалась и не падала. И, что удивительно на этой версии тоже начались падения при отладке и именно тогда, когда gdborig.exe достигает 1,2 Гб Раньше я не следил за этим процессом и не могу сказать сколько памяти он потреблял.

Comment: кстати такой вопрос уже задавали https://stackoverflow.com/q/44662971/3848611 посмотрите, может поможет

Comment: @ЕвгенийДружинин может входные данные изменились, может ещё что. В любом случае, проблему надо как-то локализовать. Вот выше ссылку привели про QFileDialog, у вас нет такого?

Comment: @ alexolut QFileDialog у меня нет, но с файл читаю.

Comment: Проблема на данный момент удивительным образом исчезла. Закомментировал все строки в функции insertImpMetValue( const CPulseMeter *pPulseMeter ) и начал по одной раскомментировать и запускать отладку. И о чудо программа начала отлаживаться без падений. Что это была за чертовщина мне не понятно. Грешу может быть на файл, который приложение должно было читать, который я заново записал.